# MongoDB: Finding same entry for two different users?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection where I store friendships between users. For example:

```
user_1 -> user_4
user_1 -> user_8
user_1 -> user_23
```

and so on.

In this collection are only these two fields and an standard „_id“ field for the entry.

Question: I want compare two different users and want to get the entries which both users have as a result.

For example:

user_1 entries in collection:

```
user_1 -> user_4
user_1 -> user_8
user_1 -> user_23
```

user_2 entries in collection:

```
user_2 -> user_4
user_2 -> user_323
user_2 -> user_23
```

When I know compare user_1 and user_2 entries, the query should give me 2 entries as a result back (the entries which are the same for both users):

```
user_4
user_23
```

So I know that user_1 and user_2 have 2 friends in common (user_4 and user_23)

**UPDATE:**

This is the current collection structure:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aacd8f60d16f81bfb2ec729"), "username" : "bellamissy95", "belongs_to_user" : ObjectId("5aacd8500d16f81bd56f0e90")}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aacd8f60d16f81bfb2ec72a"), "username" : "salome350", "belongs_to_user" : ObjectId("5aacd8500d16f81bd56f0e90")}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aacd8f60d16f81bfb2ec72b"), "username" : "jacky_25.11.17_", "belongs_to_user" : ObjectId("5aacd8500d16f81bd56f0e90")}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aacd8f60d16f81bfb2ec72c"), "username" : "jxsmin.mke", "belongs_to_user" : ObjectId("5aacd8500d16f81bd56f0e90")}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aacd8f60d16f81bfb2ec72d"), "username" : "toni_w2005", "belongs_to_user" : ObjectId("5aacd8500d16f81bd56f0e90")}

Legend:
"_id": the id of the entry
"username": name of the friend
"belongs_to_user": _id of the user entry
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not really that clear as it would really benefit to actually show how documents are represented where you really have this stored. There's always "a way" but it's what your "real" documents are like is what matters to the actual solution. I suggest you actually show that rather than some abstract version that does not accurately describe what you really have. At least from the perspective of anyone viewing the question.

Comment: @NeilLunn I updated the post and inserted the current collection structure. Hope it helps.

Comment: So how does that data relate? Each entry is a "unique" friend is it not? Is not the point to show users who share the same friends? Show some data that supports this as in what you have given so far no user shares the same "friend" with any other.

Comment: Yes, it's a typical friends relationship between 2 users. So when my system stores all relationships between people, I want to know how many friends User A and User B (in comparison) have in common. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the collection having the data is named "friendship" and is defined as

```
{ "_id" : <some unique number> , "user":"user_1","friend":"user_4"}
```

The following Javascript can be used get common friends among any **two** users.

```
var friendlist = [];
db.friendship.find({"user":{$in:['user_1','user_2']}},{"friend":1,"_id":0}).forEach(function(d) { if (friendlist.includes(d.friend) ) {print(d.friend)} ;friendlist.push(d.friend); });
```